# Implementing pop function with doubly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

```
void Stack::pop()
{
    Node* temp;
    if(top == NULL)
        return;
    temp = top;
    top = top->prev;
    top = top->next;
    delete temp;
}
```

So I am having trouble implementing the pop function in a doubly linked list.  Whenever  I build my compiler crashes.  The code above is what I'm struggling with.  I am really unsure on how to actually unlink my top node from my list.  If you guys can explain the pop function in a doubly linked list that would be great.

```
void Stack::ToString()
{
    //needs to be implemented
    Node* cursor = top; //create a temporary pointer for top
    while(cursor->next != NULL) //When debugging this is where it crashes.
        cursor = cursor->next;
    while(cursor != NULL)
    {
        cout << cursor->content << endl;
        cursor = cursor->prev;
    }
}
```

Comment: did u use `new` or `malloc` to allocate memory?

Comment: does it crash while compiling? or while running?

Comment: and what does your *free(temp)* function do?
(btw, your pop logic isn't correct. but i don't think it should crash. plz show your *free(temp)* method and tell, where does it crash? while compiling? or running?

Comment: It crashes while running.  I added my print function because I believe that may be the one causing the problems.

Comment: does your program print anything before crash?

Answer (score 0):

The logic in the function is flawed.

Let' say you have two node in the linked list:

```
  top   -> +--+
           |  |
           +--+
    (next)  ^ | (prev)
            | v
  n2    -> +--+
           |  |
           +--+
```

Then, `top->prev = n2` and `n2->next = top`.

When you execute:

```
top = top->prev;  // Now top is n2
top = top->next;  // Now top is what it used to be start with.
```

You did nothing in the list to pop `top` from the top of the list.

The fix to this problem depends on whether the list is circular or not.

If the list is not circular, you can do:

```
Node* prev = top->prev;
Node* next = top->next;
if ( prev != NULL )
{
   prev->next = next;
}
if ( next != NULL )
{
   next->prev = prev;
}
top->next = NULL;
top->prev = NULL;
```

If the list is circular, the logic needs to be a little bit more elaborate.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense.  Okay my list is not circular.  Now for my print function it's only printing out the popped value.

Comment: @user3485650 It's hard to suggest what else is tripping you up without seeing the entire code for `Stack` and how it is being tested.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the list like this pic:

[image]

And the code is clear to understand.

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
};


void Pop(struct Node *&head) {

    if (head != NULL) {

        // if list hase just one item, set head to null
        if (head->next == NULL) {
            head = head->next;
        }
        else {
            
            // copy head to temp node
            Node *tmp = new Node;
            tmp = head;

            // traverse list to raech end of it
            while (tmp->next->next != NULL)
                tmp = tmp->next;
            
            // deallocate last node
            delete tmp->next;
            tmp->next = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

For printing the list:

```
void Print(struct Node *&head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        std::cout << "list is empty!\n";
    }    
    else { 
        while (head != NULL) {
            std::cout << head->data << " ";
            head = head->next;
        }
    }
}
```